# Trying to use code for sending Harmony ONE coin to send HRC20 tokens. I made few changes but getting error

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum

Harmony One SDK [enter link description here][1]

I have used the code for sending Harmony one token to another Harmony one address.
Like ethereum, I have included transfer method to transfer HRC20 token.
But its not working.

In the reference the code for signing transaction in case we are sending tokens is not provided.

````
let encodedABI = transfer.encodeABI();

async function transferTokens() {

await setSharding(); //cross shard transaction

const txn = hmy.transactions.newTx({

to: '0x9fac0935f055882969bE6f68671B4F5673573e60', //token contract address
value: 0x0, // One coin
gasLimit: '210000',
shardID: 0,
toShardID: 0,
gasPrice: new hmy.utils.Unit('100').asGwei().toWei(),
data: encodedABI,
});

// sign the transaction
const signedTxn = await hmy.wallet.signTransaction(txn);

console.log("\n \n signed TXN:::::::::::::::::::::", signedTxn)

// to listen events
signedTxn
.observed()
.on('transactionHash', (txnHash) => {
console.log('');
console.log('--- hash ---');
console.log('');
console.log(txnHash);
console.log('');
})
.on('receipt', (receipt) => {
console.log('');
console.log('--- receipt ---');
console.log('');
console.log(receipt);
console.log('');
})
.on('cxReceipt', (receipt) => {
console.log('');
console.log('--- cxReceipt ---');
console.log('');
console.log(receipt);
console.log('');
})
.on('error', (error) => {
console.log('');
console.log('--- error ---');
console.log('');
console.log(error);
console.log('');
});

// send the txn, get [Transaction, transactionHash] as result

const [sentTxn, txnHash] = await signedTxn.sendTransaction();

// to confirm the result if it is already there

const confiremdTxn = await sentTxn.confirm(txnHash);
console.log("\n\nConfirmed TXN :::::::::::::::::::;", confiremdTxn )

// if the transactino is cross-shard transaction
if (!confiremdTxn.isCrossShard()) {
if (confiremdTxn.isConfirmed()) {
console.log('--- Result ---');
console.log('');
console.log('Normal transaction');
console.log(`${txnHash} is confirmed`);
console.log('');
process.exit();
}
}
if (confiremdTxn.isConfirmed() && confiremdTxn.isCxConfirmed()) {
console.log('--- Result ---');
console.log('');
console.log('Cross-Shard transaction');
console.log(`${txnHash} is confirmed`);
console.log('');
process.exit();
}
}

transferTokens();```


  [1]: https://github.com/harmony-one/sdk/tree/master/packages/harmony-transaction
````

Answer (score 0):

You can call signTransaction() followed by sendTransaction on the contract method.

Reference :

- https://github.com/harmony-one/sdk/blob/master/packages/harmony-contract/src/contractFactory.ts
- https://github.com/harmony-one/sdk/tree/master/packages/harmony-contract

Harmany is very early stage so recommending to check their official resources, and SDKs only..

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the chunk of code, which you should put before

> **hmy.transactions.newTx({...**

creating a new transaction object.

```
const hmy = new Harmony('https://api.s0.b.hmny.io',
    {
        chainType: ChainType.Harmony,
        chainId: ChainID.HmyTestnet,
    },
);
hmy.wallet.addByPrivateKey('YOUR PRIVATE KEY');
hmy.blockchain.getShardingStructure();
```